# ListView Header and Footer interfering with ListView operation

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I feel at this stage I may have either missed something vital or gone completely mad.

I'm trying to add a Header and Footer to my existing ListView implementation, I'm adding them like so:

```
mHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_feed_item_header, null, false);
mListView.addHeaderView(mHeader);
```

and

```
mFooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_feed_item_footer, null, false);
mListView.addFooterView(mFooter);
```

What I've found it is doing this forces me to:

- When an onItemClickListener fires, the position includes the header and footer
- After adding the footer the adapters `getView()` method uses both list items and the footer in convertView - making the implementation unusable.

Does anyone know *why* the footer is being used as a recycledView in BaseAdapter?

Comment: Adding header and footer views to a `ListView` causes your adapter to be wrapped in [a `HeaderViewListAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java), which has knock-on effects. I'm not shocked that you're encountering these sorts of problems.

Comment: Should I be using HeaderViewListerAdapter in preference to BaseAdapter? I'm finding very little in terms of examples of using HeaderViewListAdapter.

Comment: "Should I be using HeaderViewListerAdapter in preference to BaseAdapter?" -- I don't think so. More likely, you shouldn't be using header and footer views. I always found them to be troublesome, which is part of the reason why [I wrote a `MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) to replace them and offer other stuff besides.

Comment: use the overload [`addFooterView(View, Object, boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) to solve the 1st issue.